# Reverse matrix operation that makes it symmetric.

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

given a symmetric matrix $A = \frac{B+B^T}{2}$ can i retrieve B? Or has that information been lost...

Comment: No: you can't. Information is lost.

Comment: Adding any two anti symmetric matrices will result in zero.

Comment: “I'm thinking of two numbers whose average is 6.  What are they?” Can you see how that's the same question?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes, but i thought since it was B twise... there was something there.

Comment: You're part right, as @OpenBall points out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the diagonal elements of $B$, but not all of $B$. Consider:

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$